# How to zoom In and Zoom Out the image using Mouse Position on that image

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have added the picture box inside the tab panel. I am trying to apply zoom In and zoom out operation on it. Actually both operation working fine but I want to zoom in and zoom out operation that work on mouse position. means zoom In/Out the image at cursor location or at mouse position.

My code is below

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
 if (_isZoomInFlag == true)
  {
   zoomInt++;
   if (zoomInt > 4)
   {
    zoomInt = 4;
   }
    zoomPicturebox();
  }
  if (_isZoomOutFlag == true)
  {
   zoomInt--;
   if (zoomInt == -3)
   {
    zoomInt = -2;
   }
  zoomPicturebox();
 }
}

public void zoomPicturebox()
{
            pbDisplay.Width = picWidth;
            pbDisplay.Height = picHeight;

            switch (zoomInt)
            {
                case -2:
                    pbDisplay.Width = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * 0.25);
                    pbDisplay.Height = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * picRatio);

                    break;
                case -1:
                    pbDisplay.Width = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * 0.5);
                    pbDisplay.Height = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * picRatio);

                    break;
                case 0:
                    pbDisplay.Width = picWidth;
                    pbDisplay.Height = picHeight;

                    break;
                case 1:
                    pbDisplay.Width = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * 1.1);
                    pbDisplay.Height = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * picRatio);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    pbDisplay.Width = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * 1.5);
                    pbDisplay.Height = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * picRatio);

                    break;
                case 3:
                    pbDisplay.Width = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * 1.75);
                    pbDisplay.Height = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * picRatio);
                   // lblZoom.Text = ("Zoom = 175%");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pbDisplay.Width = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * 2);
                    pbDisplay.Height = Convert.ToInt32(((double)pbDisplay.Width) * picRatio);

                    break;
            }


            pbDisplay.Update();
        }
```

Zoom In image

[image]

Zoom out Image

[image]

Comment: means zoom In/Out the image at cursor location or at mouse position.  I dont know what's the meaning of it

Comment: @Rang Yes zoom in/Out handling mouse cursor position when I tried this functionality actual mouse position is at different location and zoom In/Out at different location.I want to handle Zoom In/Out at on mouse cursor location.

Comment: yep,zoom in/out in different location. but how to trigger it ? click? mouse over? or something else?

Comment: @Rang srry for I used wrong mouse event actually its OnMouseWheel event Instead of MouseMove. I have updated the code. Its on mouse wheel...

Comment: you want zoom in/out when the mouse move onto the pic and use wheel?

Comment: I just want this functionality on mouse wheel...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

picturebox has MouseWheel event, but you need give it focus at first.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    pictureBox1.MouseWheel += pictureBox1_MouseWheel;
}

void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Delta > 0)
  {
      //up
  }
  else
  {
      //down
  }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Focus();
}
```

here,in mousedown event, give it focus,and make wheel event active. then you can do it in your code.

Comment: actually there is no change its functionality works same as it is as I want zoom in and out on mouse wheel at cursor location

Comment: I see nothing in the code that would allow for zooming in at the cursor position.